# Access invalid qualifier

Tags: ms-access, vba

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

Dim BX As String
Set DBase = CurrentDb
Dim RSColours As DAO.Recordset
Set RSColours = DBase.OpenRecordset("Colours")
RSColours.MoveFirst
Do While Not RSColours.EOF
MsgBox "ZoneCode  " & RSColours!Zonecode
R = Val("&H" & Mid(RSColours![Zonecode], 1, 2))
G = Val("&H" & Mid(RSColours![Zonecode], 3, 2))
B = Val("&H" & Mid(RSColours![Zonecode], 5, 2))

BX = RSColours![Sheetzone]
                'MsgBox "length  " & BX & "   " & Len(BX)
                'MsgBox R & "/" & G & "/" & B

'BX.BackColor = RGB(R, G, B)'..............................Fails here even though BX ?= B1Z1
B1Z1.BackColor = RGB(R, G, B) '.............................Works, but I want to color more than one rectangle
RSColours.MoveNext
Loop
End Sub
```

I color several rectangles and save the Rectangle name (B1Z1 etc) and the HexColor to a table. When I reload the form I want to restore the saved colors.
The program fails when I assign a variable (BX) and try to set the Backcolor.

If I use the constant "B1Z1" this works.  Is what I am attempting possible.?

Answer (score 0):

You need the object by the string:

```
Me(BX).BackColor = RGB(R, G, B)
```